# Accessing isActive on NavLink in React Router with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom@6.42` and have the following react component:

```
import { Link as NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

interface SidebarNavItemProps {
  name: string;
  path: string;
  icon: JSX.Element;
}

const SidebarNavItem = (props: SidebarNavItemProps) => {
  const navLinkCssClasses = ({isActive }): string => {
    return `flex group-hover:text-primary-700 group-hover:bg-primary-50 text-gray-700 font-semibold text-base px-3 py-2 rounded-md ${
      isActive ? "text-primary-700 bg-primary-50" : ""
    }`;
  };

  return (
    <li className="group mb-1">
      <NavLink className={navLinkCssClasses} to={props.path}>
        {props.icon}
        {props.name}
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  );
};

export default SidebarNavItem;
```

I am using TypeScript and the compiler is not happy. I'm getting two errors:

> TS7031: Binding element 'isActive' implicitly has an 'any' type.

> TS2322: Type '({ isActive }: { isActive: any; }) => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I tried changing `className={navLinkCssClasses}` to `className={navLinkCssClasses({isActive})}` but that still did not help. What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you getting `isActive` from? Is it passed to the `SideBarNavItem` component props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `isActive` prop is only available for `NavLink` component. In your code, `Link` is imported as `NavLink`. What you have to do is import `NavLink` itself.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: Good catch, sorry my IDE did that :(

Answer (score 2):

You've got two issues here, which should be easy to fix:

1. As @arjun.dev points out, you've imported `Link as NavLink` where you should have imported `NavLink`—React Router's `Link` component doesn't take a function as a `className`, where `NavLink` does.
2. Since `navLinkCssClasses` is a function, its parameters (`isActive`) must be typed correctly

```typescript
// this is important
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

/* ... */

const SidebarNavItem = (props: SidebarNavItemProps) => {
  // make sure to type the parameters of this function! isActive is a boolean 
  const navLinkCssClasses = ({ isActive }: { isActive: boolean }): string => {
    return `flex group-hover:text-primary-700 group-hover:bg-primary-50 text-gray-700 font-semibold text-base px-3 py-2 rounded-md ${
      isActive ? "text-primary-700 bg-primary-50" : ""
    }`;
  };

  return (
    <li className="group mb-1">
      <NavLink className={navLinkCssClasses} to={props.path}>
        {props.icon}
        {props.name}
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the typescript `: { isActive: boolean }` also helped <3